# Search string in a file and save subset of the result in powershell

Tags: powershell, substring

```
File.txt

ParaApp :Success

ParaApp Desc :9/27/2022 3:07 AM load was completed successfully. Total duration 10 min.

CiscApp :Success

CiscApp Desc :9/27/2022 4:03 AM Incremental load was completed successfully. Total duration 4 min.

LitApp :Success

LitApp Desc :9/27/2022 2:10 AM Incremental load was completed successfully. Total duration 10 min.


Powershell: 

Search for pattern 'ParaApp Desc :' and get date, success msg & time in separate variable.


$SearchName = "ParaApp Desc :"

$Msg1 = Get-Content .\File.txt | Select-String $SearchName
```

$Msg1 is showing full line but cant do substring of the result and save in variable.

**Question: Would like to store following values in variables and display.**

```
$var1 - 9/27/2022 3:07 AM 

$var2 - load was completed successfully

$var3 - 10 min
```

I have tried many ways, still no luck :)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. ;-)

Comment: Regardless of that - could you please format your question to make it possible to distinguish between text and code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What a pity that you get answers anyway. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Read file, get line and match related patterns
$matchingPatterns = gc [path] | ?{$_ -match 'ParaApp Desc :'} | select-string '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2} [A,P]M|load was .*?\.|\d{1,3} min' -AllMatches

#Fill variables 
$var1 = $matchingPatterns.matches.groups.value[0]
$var2 = $matchingPatterns.matches.groups.value[1]
$var3 = $matchingPatterns.matches.groups.value[2]

#Output
$var1
9/27/2022 3:07 AM
$var2
load was completed successfully.
$var3
10 min

#Pattern
'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2} [A,P]M' #= 1-2 digits slash 1-2 digits slash 4 digits space 1-2 digits colon 2 digits space AM or PM
'load was .*?\.' #= load was everything until first dot
'\d{1,3} min' #= 1-3 digits space min

#To select everything starting from the time
'\d{1,2}:\d{2}.*'

#If you only want the information before or after AM/PM you could also use split
$split = (gc [path] | ?{$_ -match 'ParaApp Desc :'}) -split ' [A,P]M '
$split[0] #before
$split[1] #after

#Same game for 'ParaApp :' 
$split = (gc [path] | ?{$_ -match 'ParaApp Desc :'}) -split 'ParaApp Desc :'
$split[1]
#or simply by replace
$replace = (gc [path] | ?{$_ -match 'ParaApp Desc :'}) -replace 'ParaApp Desc :',$null
```

Comment: Just one more expression: How to select everything after the string.

LIike 4:03 AM 'Incremental load was completed successfully.' Total duration 4 min.

Select everything after AM and before .Total

AND: Select everything after 'ParaApp :'